# Linebreak in section heading

Tags: sectioning, section-titles

I have this section heading.  I need it formated as such but the linebreaks are not passing down.  It is currently over flowing the page.  The \ does not work in this situation.

```
\section{\normalsize\sffamily\underline{Чтение/Прослушивание \\ в Течении Часа}}
```

of course I know this works

```
\section{Чтение/Прослушивание \\ в Течении Часа}
```

What am I doing wrong please.

ANSWERED IN COMMENT:

```
\section{\normalsize\sffamily\underline{Чтение/Прослушивание} \\ \normalsize\sffamily\underline{в Течении Часа}}
```

Comment: `\underline{aaa}\\ \underline{bbb}` but really you should not have any formatting in the argument  of  `\section` the formatting of section headings should be specified by the document class.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank You.  It is an extremely small book of only 84mm x 134mm.  I have not been able to find anywhere to edit the length/width allowed for a section title.  You can just point me in the right direction I would love that.

Comment: You could load the `ulem` package and replace `\underline` with `\uline`.